# What is the intention/benefit of malloc returning type void *?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory-management, malloc

Knowing more C++ than C I wondered if someone could explain the reason why malloc() always returns a pointer of type void, rather than malloc having been implemented with some mechanism which allows it to return a pointer of the type the user passed in? It just seems a little "hacky" constantly explicitly casting the returned void pointer to the type you want.

Comment: The type the user passed in? You mean `size_t`?

Comment: there is no generics in C, and malloc doesnt have to be a macro. So you dont have a choice than defining malloc return type as void* .

Comment: Note that you don't have to (and according to some, including me, 
*shouldn't*) [cast the return value of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/395760). In C, there is an implicit conversion from `void *` to any pointer type.

Comment: Well, if you want code that compiles cleanly in C++ mode, you'll need the cast. That can be very important for portability.

Comment: @UmNyobe, first, modern C has generics. Then, your argument only holds if you insist that you want to implement such functions in C itself.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, what is C++ mode? C and C++ are distinct languages, code written in one generally is not very good code for the other. In particular, C++ code should never use `malloc` but `new`, directly. So there is no real need for that in C++.

Comment: @JensGustedt Compiling C as C++ does sometimes happen. With some toolsets, it's far easier to just compile everything as C++ instead of selectively compiling some files as C. Sometimes you don't even have a C compiler. There's a reason for `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif` seen in C files all over the world.

Comment: @Jens: every platform I've ever worked on has one compiler for both C and C++ which is toggled with a switch.

Comment: @dalman, the technique that you are describing is for interface compatibility and not more. Compiling executable code that is written for one of the languages with a compiler for the other has many subtle problems, ranging from different implementation of `enum` types to different rules for casting. It is just not a good idea.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, many compilers use the same backend for a lot of languages. gcc e.g is able to compile at least 5 different programming languages. This doesn't mean e.g that it makes much sense to compile fortran with the C++ frontend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in C you don't have to do the cast, so your point is moot.  That is, these two statements are 100% equivalent:

```
 char *x = malloc(100);
 char *y = (char *)malloc(100);
```

Conversions to and from `void *` are implicit in C.  So, to address your question, the *very reason* `malloc` returns `void *` is so that you *don't* have to cast.

Besides that, in C there's no way to pass type information around, so doing something like:

```
 char *x = malloc(100, char);
```

is not possible.

If you're in C++, the cast is necessary, but you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway - that's what `new` is for, and it does handle the type information correctly.

Comment: Passing the type is possible using a macro: `#define ALLOC(t, n) (((t) *)malloc(sizeof(t) * (n)))`. It's just not necessary.

Comment: @larsmans - yes, but OP is asking why `malloc` itself doesn't have such an interface, I think.

Comment: I think so too, and +1 for your answer. I was just replying to the "is not possible" remark.

Answer (score 3):

It's not hacky at all, from C standard ISO/IEC 9899 2011, section 6.2.2.3:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

So a pointer to `void*` is a valid pointer to whatever type you want without the need of explicit casting.

In addition to this you can't dynamically pass a type to a function to let so that it will return the correct type, you can pass just the size itself (so malloc would be able to allocate `size_t count * size_t size` but not return the correctly type in any case).

Answer (score 0):

C has no mechanism for "passing a type" at all. Also, in C, conversion from void* to a pointer of any other type is automatic (no cast is needed) so malloc works naturally in C. It's only in C++ where malloc requires casts to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons, first, malloc doesn't know why you need memory. So it just return number of bytes asked to return. Secondly you cannot de-reference void * easily so it can help you to avoid accidents.

```
int *p;
p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```